# SwiftUI - DragGesture and .onDelete conflict

Tags: swift, gesture, drag, gesture-recognition

I have a conflict between gestures:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {

@State var showSearchBar = true

var body : some View {
            NavigationView {
                 Form {
                      ForEach(//code) { values in
                      NavigationLink(//code)
                      }
                      .onDelete(perform: //delete action)
                      }
                    .simultaneousGesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged({ gesture in
                                if gesture.location.y > gesture.startLocation.y {
                                    showSearchBar = false
                                } else {
                                    showSearchBar = true
                                }
                            })
                    )}}}
```

However, both gestures don't work. If I remove the .simultaneousGesture, the .onDelete works, but if I leave both, only the .simultaneousGesture works. How can I make both work?

Thanks to everyone who will help me!

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you raise this with Apple developer support.